# Show server files in a <select>

Tags: php, html

I need to show the files stored in a folder called "uploads" in a `<select>`. In this moment my code is the following:

```
<?php

  echo "<select class='select' name='delete'>";
  function get_directory22($path){

  if (is_dir($path)){
   $gestor = opendir($path);

   while (($file= readdir($gestor)) !== false)  {

    $complete_path = $path . "/" . $file;

       if ($file!= "." && $file != ".." && $file!= ".htaccess") {
        if (is_dir($complete_path)) {
         echo '<option value= "uploads/client1/' . $file. '"</option>';
           get_directory22($complete_path);
           } else {
             echo 'error';
             }
           }
         }
         closedir($gestor);
         } else {
           echo "No es una ruta de directorio valida<br/>";
       }

     }
       get_directory22("uploads/client1");
        echo "</select>";
 ?>
```

I do not know why is it failing but the select shows nothing more than a white space.

Comment: The line `echo '<option value= "uploads/seat/' . $archivo . '"</option>';`produces invalid html. Maybe that's the error?

Comment: I will try it now! Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line

```
echo '<option value= "uploads/client1/' . $archivo . '"</option>';
```

with this

```
echo '<option value= "uploads/client1/' . $archivo . '">' . $archivio . '</option>';
```

Also pressing `F12` and looking at the html code of your website may help for future problems

Comment: Great man, it is working!

Answer (score 2):

Bad html:

```
     echo '<option value= "uploads/client1/' . $archivo . '"</option>';
                                                            ^---
```

You're generating

```
<option value= "uploads/client/1/foo/bar"</option>
                                         ^---missing >
```

Had you bothered opening your browser's 'view source' or DOM inspector, you'd have seen the mangled html right away.

Comment: Yes, my fault... It is difficult to check in my browser's view source, it is all inside a javascript panel (download zone, delete zone and upload zone). I try now to put the missing character and I update the post.
Thanks for your time!